# Compiling java app in terminal

Tags: java, jar, compiler-errors, classpath, javac

I'm on linux, created a `testjavaapp` folder in `/home/Downloads` directory, then added three files `MyApp.java`, `MyLib.java` and `hppc-0.4.1.jar` files into that folder.

`MyLib.java` starts with:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.carrotsearch.hppc.IntArrayList;

public final class MyLib {
...
```

while `MyApp.java` starts with:

```
import static MyLib.*;
import com.carrotsearch.hppc.IntArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
...
```

When I execute:

```
[myself@laptop ~]$ cd Downloads/testjavaapp/
[myself@laptop testjavaapp]$ javac -cp '.:/home/myself/Downloads/testjavaapp/hppc-0.4.1.jar' MyLib.java
```

the java compiler creates `MyLib.class` without any problem. But when I execute:

```
[myself@laptop testjavaapp]$ javac -cp '.:/home/myself/Downloads/testjavaapp/hppc-0.4.1.jar' MyApp.java
```

it barks:

```
MyApp.java:1: error: cannot find symbol
import static MyLib.*;
              ^
  symbol: class MyLib
```

It looks like I properly add the `.jar` library but improperly the local static library.

Could you please help me to fix it?

Comment: create MyLib subdirectory and move your MyLib.java into it and compile. Now comeback to the parent directory and compile MyApp.java

Comment: add `Downloads` dir to classpath or if you are making different dir to build java class files then you can add that to your classpath.

Comment: to rags: I created a folder `libs`, added there `MyLib.java` and `hppc-0.4.1.jar` and it is compiled but `MyApp.java` is not.

Comment: MyLib does not have a package statement, hence its in the default package and should be in the root folder alongside MyApp (which is also in the default package)

Comment: Alright, moving back to a root folder, but still it was not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this seems pretty obvious, so I may be missing something

> javac -cp '.:/home/myself/Downloads/testjavaapp/hppc-0.4.1.jar' *.java

**Edit**

Yes, the obvious I missed is that static imports don't work for default packages. [This bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4989710) has some discussion about why Java acts this way, and it was eventually closed as "not a defect" -- it's the way Java was designed to behave. Default package just has some unexpected behavior, and this is one of the reasons why programmers are encouraged to never used the default package.

Comment: Cool, I created `libs` folder, added there .jar and `MyLib.java` class with line `package libs`, then compiled then `cd ..` to a parent folder and finally it was compiled successfully.